# (Accelerated Mobile Pages) AMP Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, amp-html

I am trying to learn AMP Analytics. I stumbled upon this statement which I am unable to understand.

> Since analytics priority is lower compared to content on the page, it's recommended that clicks are tracked using a browser redirect to avoid click loss.

Can someone please make me understand how redirect helps in avoiding click loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that's referred to is that analytics have low priority, i.e. they are not guaranteed to fire immediately. Clicking on a link navigates you to a different page, which may happen before analytics has a chance to fire a click event.

Thus, it's safer to track links through other means, like a redirect, rather than to rely on `amp-analytics` which may result in a race condition.

Comment: Thanks. But the purpose of redirect is still unclear to me. Can you explain a bit more. How does it avoids this race condition?

Comment: If your website `example.com` has a link to `stackoverflow.com`, you can instead link to `example.com/redirect?url=stackoverflow.com` and then have your `redirect` endpoint track this click on the server-side.